# Using malloc for a recursive function which gets a different size of memory everytime the function is called

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, malloc

I'm trying to implement a function

```
int array(char *str, int length)
```

which calls character array, and copies only specific elements onto another array, which has to be the same length as the original `str` array.

But this function needs to be recursive, and I don't see a way to declare this 'copied' array,

since if I do

```
char copied(length);
```

inside the function,

as the function calls itself recursively the array will be reset for every run.

I'm limited in making another function that takes length as its variables, so that's not a way.

---

```
struct variables {
    int counter;
    char bra[500];
    int maxb;
    int findtheking[500];
    int numoright;
};

struct variables mat = { 0, '\0', 0 , 0, 0 };

int matches(char* str, int len) {
    if (mat.counter >= strlen(str)) {
        if (mat.bra[strlen(str)-1] == '(') {
            mat.counter = 0;
            mat.bra[0] = '\0';
            return 0;
        }
        else if (mat.bra[strlen(str)-1]  == '0') {
            mat.counter = 0;
            mat.bra[0] = '\0';
            return 1;
        }


    }
    else {
        if (str[mat.counter] == '(') {
            mat.bra[len-1] = str[mat.counter];
            mat.counter++;
            matches(str, len - 1);

        }
        else if (str[mat.counter] == ')') {
            if (mat.bra[len] == '(') {
                mat.counter++;
                mat.bra[len] = '0';
                matches(str, len + 1);
            }
            else {
                mat.counter = 0;
                mat.bra[0] = '\0';
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            mat.counter++;
            matches(str, len);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a function I made for my CS HW, already done and submitted.

It takes in a string of characters, and checks the brackets if they are matched correctly.

This code is in func.c, and takes in str from main.c.

- I can only use recursive way, no for/while loops.

To solve the problem, I made this function to find brackets in the string, and if '(' is found the function puts it in a array called mat.bra, which I set its size 500 because I couldn't find a way to make mat.bra have size 'len'.

This code won't work for strings above 500 elements, so I was wondering if there is a way to make mat.bra size 'len' to not worry about the total number of characters on str.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're saying ... you can't "call" an array, and how is the `array()`  function supposed to copy "only specific elements"? How are those specified, with that prototype?  Please show more code.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the question is unclear. If you already have some code, please add it in the form of a [mcve]. And then, explain your problem a bit better please, for example, explain why you think "*this function needs to be recursive*" and what should happen in this recursion. (side note: don't see any reference to C#, so removed the tag)

Comment: Why do you need recursion in first place?

Comment: Sry, I'll add my code in a minute

Comment: I added my code to the question; if i need to improve more, please tell me and I'll try my best!

Comment: Unrelated, most of that function doesn't have a defined `return` value (the entire outer `else` scenario, and the implicit tail `else` scenario in the top `if` block), so if this is as you submitted it... oops. To answer your question (at least I think it was your question), making `bra` a `char*` and managing it's size with another member `bra_size` and dynamic allocation is an option, though I'm not convinced you need it.